# Times New Roman fonts and maths WITHOUT mathptmx

Tags: fonts, math-mode, mathptmx

I do not want to use `mathptmx` package since using this LaTeX=>PDF is not not compiling. Please suggest me to achieve Times New Roman Fonts and math environment, anything other than `mathptmx`.

Comment: `mathptmx` does not use Times _New Roman_ fonts, it uses Times (one of the "standard" postscript fonts). You'll be better out with `txfonts`, which does similar job, but much better. If you really need Times New Roman (font shipped with MS Win), I guess, you have to use xetex.

Comment: Don't waste your time by trying to avoid to solve the problem with mathptmx. You simply haven't install every needed package (it is a known problem of TeXniccenter that it blocks quite often the on-the-fly installation). Imho there are better editors around.

Answer (score 32):

The `txfonts` package used to be the answer, but since some days a new package has been developed based on the first one, with new metric files for fonts that should avoid some of the weaknesses shown by `txfonts`:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

- Compiled with `mathptmx`

[image]

- Compiled with `txfonts`

[image]

- Compiled with `newtxmath`

[image]

---

A word of advice about the TeX distribution: disk space is not a big issue nowadays. Unless you're running TeX on a very small device, do a full install.

Comment: `newtxmath` seems to have the nicest spacing, looking at the interval of the integral an the exponent of the expression in parentheses.

Comment: @doncherry The author's aim was exactly to correct the small spacing issues of `txfonts`: look at the `x^{2}`, where the exponent is correctly detached from the basis. Of course `mathptmx` is too cheap for quality typesetting: it does its job, but it cannot be recommended for an important project.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to egreg answer, there is also the [MathTime Professional 2](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font, whose lite version is freely available. IMHO it is the best looking math font for Times, and a number of prefessional math journals use that.

With `\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}`:
[image: MTPro2 example]

Comment: fyi, This package is not part of texlive 2013? I get error `mtpro2 not found` using the command you show above.

Comment: @Nasser Yes, there seems to be a licensing issue. Anyway, you can find the package on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite).