# Suggest a "nice" font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)

Tags: fonts, packages

My goal is to choose a "nice" font family (serif, sans serif, monospace, and "math") for my basic LaTeX template.

I know the default setting (`Computer Modern`'s family) is a very good choice.
However, I want something a bit less "by default", a bit less "used by everyone else"...
Also, I would like something with an increased readability (relative to the default setting, i.e. `Computer Modern`) both for on paper reading and for on screen reading, and something that is at least as good with math typing and printing.
Finally, I would like a solution that I could easily use on other computers or give/suggest to a friend (i.e. it should ideally come with most standard LaTeX distributions at the present time (June 2012)).
These are my **motivations** or goals.

Initially, I used `pslatex` which uses Times, Helvetica, and Courier (or slightly modified versions of them).
But then I discovered that `pslatex` is outdated, and that I should use either (just) `txfonts` or (the three) `mathptmx`, `helvet` ([scaled=.90]), and `courier`.
Then I read that `tgtermes` is better (or at least prefered by some people).
Even later (June 2012), I then heard that `newtx` is even better (`\usepackage[varg, cmintegrals, cmbraces, ]{newtxtext,newtxmath}`).

But in the `newtx`/`newtxtext`/`newtxmath` documentation (and the internet follow-up searches), I got very confused about using `lmodern`, `textcomp`, `bm`, `amsmath`, `amsfonts`, `amssymb`, `libertine`, `libertineotf`, `libertine-legacy` (edit: initial post had a mistake ('libertine-heritage')), etc...

Now I am completely lost!

Considering my motivations, what would you answer me if I asked you:

- which ones could I use ('alone'),
- which ones could I use together,
- which ones "should" I use ('alone'),  and
- which ones "should" I use together?

Added "bonus" problem: I would like to keep the characters per line ratio to a nice, comfortable level (i.e. between 60 and 75), and, ideally, to be able to set it. (Please directly see, answer, and refer to: [Nicely force 66 characters per line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line))

Note: I work on both Windows and Unix/Linux. I compile with pdflatex (sorry don't know what capitalisation makes most consensus :))

Here I present you a reduced version of my template, relevant to this question (for you to play with if you want to). *Note that I added a second, updated version of this template as edit at the end of this question post. Feel free to use it.*

```
\documentclass[draft, pdftex, a4paper, 12pt, openbib, ]{article}

\usepackage[pdftex, final, pdfstartview = FitV, linktocpage = false, breaklinks = true, ]{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}   % Improved interface for floating objects ; add [H] option

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FONTS and ENCODING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lmodern}        % Latin Modern family of fonts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % fontenc is oriented to output, that is, what fonts to use for printing characters. 
                            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc 
                            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc
% WHICH ONE TO CHOOSE?
    % \usepackage{pslatex}
    % \usepackage[varg, cmintegrals, cmbraces, ]{newtxtext,newtxmath} % libertine, uprightGreek (U.S.) or slantedGreek (ISO), 
    % \usepackage{tgtermes}                
    % \usepackage{txfonts}
    % \usepackage{mathptmx}
    % \usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
    % \usepackage{courier}
% \usepackage{textcomp}     % required for special glyphs
% \usepackage{bm}           % load after all math to give access to bold math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % inputenc allows the user to input accented characters directly from the keyboard; 
                            % utf8x : much broader but less compatible ; latin1 : old?
                            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc

% References:
% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6637
% ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf
% ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf
% http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/latex/latex32-LaTeXAndFonts/single/
% http://thirteen-01.stat.iastate.edu/wiki/LaTeXFonts
% http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/beginlatex/html/chapter8.html
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/times-new-roman-fonts-and-maths-without-mathptmx


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LAY OUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line
% (must be after pslatex, tgterms, etc...)
% \usepackage[DIV=calc]{typearea}
%
% \usepackage[cm]{fullpage} % set 'default' full page
% \usepackage{geometry}     % margins?
\usepackage{lipsum}         % to fill in with arbitrary text
\widowpenalty = 4000        % help suppress widows,  default = 4,000 (?), from 0 to 10 000 (from 300 to 1 000 recommended, 10 000 not recommended)
\clubpenalty  = 4000        % help suppress orphans, default = 4,000 (?), from 0 to 10 000 (from 300 to 1 000 recommended, 10 000 not recommended)
\usepackage[final, babel]{microtype} % many good lay-out/justification effects, see:
                                     % texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/pdflatex-microtype/


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% AMS MATH %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage{amsmath}      % loads amstext, amsbsy, amsopn but not amssymb
                            % equation stuff (eqref, subequations, equation, align, gather, flalign, multline, alignat, split...)
% \usepackage{amsfonts}     % may be redundant with amsmath
% \usepackage{amssymb}      % may be redundant with amsmath



\begin{document}

\title{Correlation of procrastination and \LaTeX}
\author{Anne Onymous}

\maketitle

\textrm{\lipsum[11]}

\textsf{\lipsum[11]}

\texttt{\lipsum[11]}

\section{Alibaba and the 40 thieves}

\subsection{La vie est un long fleuve tranquille}

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \left( 6 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:**

---

Trying to wrap up and put everything together (after both this post and "[Nicely force 66 characters per line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line)", I give here my template with whatever I felt was most relevant (or cool :)). Enjoy!

(Note that the .tex source file is embedded in the .pdf output file!)

(New) Template:

```
% \RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
    %
    % http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/nag/nag.pdf
    % 
    % Check for many common mistakes, and give hints on what to use instead.
    % However, always refer to l2tabu for more detailed explanations.
    % Orthodox checks for pitfalls that are not technically incorrect.
    % If you know what you’re doing, omit orthodox.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% CLASS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[draft, pdftex, a4paper, 12pt, openbib, ]{article} % openright, doubleside, twoside, letterpaper, a4paper, ...
% draft or final option also in:
%  - fixme
%  - graphicx
%  - hyperref
%  - microtype
%  - ...?


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% BABEL and LANGUAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage{listings}                   % it is a source code printer for LATEX
                                          % \lstset{language=Python}
                                          % \lstinputlisting{source.py}   % command used to pretty-print stand alone files
\usepackage[english]{babel}               % [french, frenchb, english, ]
    % http://forum.mathematex.net/latex-f6/les-puces-avec-babel-t4256.html
    % http://www.grappa.univ-lille3.fr/FAQ-LaTeX/11.1.html


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FONTS and ENCODING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% See:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math-i-am
%

\usepackage{lmodern}        % Latin Modern family of fonts. Very much like Computer Modern, but with many more glyphs 
                            % (e.g., for characters with accents, glyphs, cedillas, etc)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % fontenc is oriented to output, that is, what fonts to use for printing characters. 
                            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc 
                            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc

% Change some fonts or the whole font family (i.e. serif, sans serif, monospace, and 'math')
    % \usepackage[varg, cmintegrals, cmbraces, ]{newtxtext,newtxmath}  % Other options: libertine, uprightGreek (U.S.) or slantedGreek (ISO), etc...
    % \usepackage{tgtermes}                                            % Only serif ("TeX-Gyre" text)
    % \usepackage{kpfonts}                                             % "Kepler" fonts
    % \usepackage{mathpazo}                                            % Based on Hermann Zapf's Palatino font
    % \usepackage{txfonts}                                             % More than a decade old
    % \usepackage{pslatex}                                             % Obsolete?
    %  - \usepackage{mathptmx}
    %  - \usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
    %  - \usepackage{courier}

% \usepackage{textcomp}     % required for special glyphs
% \usepackage{bm}           % load after all math to give access to bold math
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % inputenc allows the user to input accented characters directly from the keyboard; 
                            % utf8x : much broader but less compatible ; latin1 : old?
                            % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44694/fontenc-vs-inputenc

% See:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line
%
% pslatex is a very obsolete package and that its descendant mathptmx is rather inadequate for serious typesetting involving math.
% If you don't need mathematics, other choices based on (Linotype) Times Roman are
%  - tgtermes
%  - newtxtext (based on txfonts, but with corrected metrics) (with its companion math package newtxmath)
%
%
% See:
% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=6637
%
% (times, helvet, courier)
% pslatex and txfonts produce (almost) same resutls.
% pslatex supposedly obsolete
% txfonts supposedly up-to-date
%
%
% See:
% ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf
% or 
% ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf
% in
% 2.3.3 pslatex.sty
%
% pslatex uses a Courier font scaled too narrowly.
% Its main disadvantage is that it does not work with T1 and TS1 encodings.
% So replace:
% \usepackage{pslatex} or \usepackage{txfonts}
% by all three:
% - \usepackage{mathptmx}
% - \usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
% - \usepackage{courier}
%
%
% See:
% http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/latex/latex32-LaTeXAndFonts/single/
% or http://thirteen-01.stat.iastate.edu/wiki/LaTeXFonts
% or http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/beginlatex/html/chapter8.html
%
% When changing fonts, you can change all of the default fonts at once with the following commands:
% 
% Command     Changes the defaults to
% 
% times       Times, Helvetica, Courier
% pslatex     same as Times, but uses a specially narrowed Courier. This is preferred over Times because of the way it handles Courier.
% newcent     New Century Schoolbook, Avant Garde, Courier
% palatino    Palatino, Helevetica, Courier
% palatcm     changes the Roman to Palatino only, but uses CM mathematics
% kpfonts     "Kepler" fonts. A very nicely evolved set of fonts also based originally on Palatino, but with many special features.
%
%
% See:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math-i-am
%
% There are, of course, many other font packages, most of which provide "only" text-mode fonts.
% Among these are the "TeX-Gyre" font families: 
%  - Termes (a Times Roman clone), 
%  - Pagella (a Palatino clone), and 
%  - Schola (a Century Schoolbook clone); 
% one would load the packages tgtermes, tgpagella, and tgschola, respectively, to access these fonts.
% However, as these are text fonts, you still need to choose a suitable math font.
% 
% Still another possibility you may want to look into is the Linux Libertine font family, to be loaded via the libertine-legacy package.
% If you like this text font and wish to employ the newtxmath package, be sure to load the newtxmath package with the libertine option set;
% doing so will set up a special set of math-mode fonts that harmonizes well with the libertine text fonts.
% 
%
% See also:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/times-new-roman-fonts-and-maths-without-mathptmx
%
%
% For a comparison, in:
% /home/christophe/Personal/Truc_Et_Astuce_Informatik/LaTeX/comparison_font_types/,
% see: 
% computer.pdf  lmodern.pdf  pslatex.pdf  test_font_type.pdf  three_replacements.pdf  txfonts.pdf
%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% AMS MATH %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage{amsmath}      % loads amstext, amsbsy, amsopn but not amssymb
                            % equation stuff (eqref, subequations, equation, align, gather, flalign, multline, alignat, split...)
% \usepackage{amsfonts}     % may be redundant with amsmath
% \usepackage{amssymb}      % may be redundant with amsmath
% \numberwithin{equation}{section}  % reset equation counters at start of each "section" and prefix numbers by section number
% \numberwithin{figure}{section}    % reset figure   counters at start of each "section" and prefix numbers by section number


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LAY OUT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% See:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59626/nicely-force-66-characters-per-line
% (must be after pslatex, tgterms, etc...)
%
% a) (but works mostly for a4paper, and changes top and bottom margin too...)
% \usepackage[DIV=calc]{typearea}
%
% or
%
% b) (but you have to choose the value and the margin ratio depending on the class...)
% \newlength{\alphabet}
% \settowidth{\alphabet}{\normalfont abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
% \usepackage{geometry}
% \geometry{%
% textwidth=2.5\alphabet,% (Note: 2.5 * 26 = 65)
% hmarginratio={2:3}}    % (Problem: geometry uses 2:3 as default for twoside and 1:1 for oneside,
%                        % independently of what the class thinks about the margins)

% \usepackage{layout}       % use \layout in the tex file to see the values
% \usepackage{layouts}      % it extends the functionality of layout, allowing you to do much, much more
                            % some commands: \pagelayout, \pagevalues, \pagedesign, ...
% \usepackage[cm]{fullpage} % set 'default' full page
% \usepackage{geometry}     % very customizable margins. Under some (rare) circumstances, should be loaded after hyperref
% \usepackage{anysize}      % \marginsize{left}{right}{top}{bottom}
% \usepackage{pdflscape}    % include landscape layout pages (automatically rotate pages in pdf file for easier reading)
% \usepackage{multicol}     % for multi column environment
\usepackage{lipsum}         % to fill in with arbitrary text
\widowpenalty = 4000        % help suppress widows,  default = 4,000 (?), from 0 to 10 000 (from 300 to 1 000 recommended, 10 000 not recommended)
\clubpenalty  = 4000        % help suppress orphans, default = 4,000 (?), from 0 to 10 000 (from 300 to 1 000 recommended, 10 000 not recommended)
\usepackage[final, babel]{microtype} % many good lay-out/justification effects, see:
                                     % texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/pdflatex-microtype/


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% EMBED FILEs %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{embedfile}    % embed (attach) any files (eg tex source) to a PDF document.
                          % Currently only supported driver is pdfTEX >= 1.30 in PDF mode
\embedfile{to_post.tex}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% EASY EDITS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{ifdraft}        % ask for selective behavior depending on the draft option (used for waterdraftmark, not draftmark)
% \usepackage{comment}      % provide new {comment} environment: all text inside the environment is ignored.
% \usepackage{fixme}        % allow nice comment / warning system, displayed in draft mode in right margin ; % [status=draft]
% \usepackage{lineno}       % number all lines in left margin if activated with \linenumbers
% \linenumbers


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% GRAPHICX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage[final]{graphicx} % options = [final]  = all graphics displayed, regardless of draft option in class
                               % options = [pdftex] = necessary (?) if import PDF files
                               % no option : when importing ps- and eps-files (?)
% \graphicspath{{../images/}}  % tell LaTeX where to look for images
% \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf, .PDF, .jpg, .JPG, .jpeg, .JPEG, .png, .PNG, .bmp, .BMP, .eps, .ps}
\usepackage{float}                      % Improved interface for floating objects ; add [H] option


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% FILIGREE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% draftmark : newer and better package but not on Phil's computers,
% in particular, draftmark has a "ifdraft" option included...
%
\ifdraft{
\usepackage{draftwatermark} % add watermark ("draft", "confidential"...)
                            % option: [firstpage] (insert on only the first page)
\SetWatermarkText{COPY~---~DRAFT}
\SetWatermarkAngle{55}
\SetWatermarkScale{6.0}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.85}
\SetWatermarkFontSize{12 pt}
}{}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% HYPERREF (last) then HYPCAP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% See:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before
%
\usepackage[
pdftex, 
final,                      % if you do    want to have clickable-colorful links
pdfstartview = FitV,
linktocpage  = false,       % ToC, LoF, LoT place hyperlink on page number, rather than entry text
breaklinks   = true,        % so long urls are correctly broken across lines
% pagebackref  = false,     % add page number in bibliography and link to position in document where cited
]{hyperref}

% \usepackage{cleveref} % enhance cross-referencing, allow full formatting, commands:
                        % \cref, \Cref, \crefrange, \cref{eq2,eq1,eq3,eq5,thm2,def3}
                        % supposedly better than \autoref as provided by hyperref

% \usepackage[all]{hypcap} % when link to float (using hyperref), link anchors to beginning (instead of below) float


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TITLE PAGE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{}
\author{This example's author's name.}
\date{\today}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% THE ACTUAL DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

% desactivate microtype protrusion for all "list of..."
% \microtypesetup{protrusion=false}

% \tableofcontents
% \listoftables
% \listoffigures

% reactivate microtype protrusion after all "list of..."
% \microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\title{Correlation of procrastination and \LaTeX}

\maketitle

\textrm{\lipsum[11]}

\textsf{\lipsum[11]}

\texttt{\lipsum[11]}

\section{Alibaba and the 40 thieves}

\subsection{La vie est un long fleuve tranquille}

% \lipsum[11]

\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \left( 6 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \right)^\frac{1}{4}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1-7]

\end{document}
```

Cheers.

Comment: I just skimmed over the `newtxdoc` documentation - very cool package bundle! Starting from page 7, he provides a couple of examples. Seems like the combination of `\usepackage{libertine}` together with `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` provides the nicest looking formulae. I actually really really like this!

Thank you for pointing those packages out.

Comment: @mSSM: That's another goal of my question, to tell others about these awesome packages :)

Comment: I used `mathpazo`. Looks (almost ?) like `pxfonts`, but has the benefit of better kerning management. Maybe it's not very original, but IMHO looks very nice. `:)`

Comment: It's hard to buy your excuse of not wanting Computer Modern because "it's used by everyone else" and then talk about Times. `:-)` *This* is really used by almost everybody.

Comment: Side note: consider changing 'when' you load [hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/8528)

Comment: @jon: Could you please elaborate a bit, or give some pointers/references? (Note that in my actual template I load `hyperref` almost last (only `glossaries` and `minitoc` are loaded after, as I believe it is supposed to be)).

Comment: @egreg: Yes, I realize now that it is kind of inconsistent. Lets say that I had different reasons initially, that now I still want to know or do differently, and that I need an 'official' excuse. :)

Comment: @Christophe -- Then you are probably fine.  I only had the example above to judge.  (The link in the above comment gives more information than I could do here.)

Comment: maybe this question is interesting for you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59403/8569

Comment: If fonts are really important to you, you should also consider using XeLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. With XeLaTeX you can easily use all otf fonts, including professional fonts like Minion Pro, Myriad Pro or Rotis (to name some of my favourite fonts).

Comment: I've found this really big comparison, with different fonts and with different engines. http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/gust_e-foundry-math_fonts-presentation.pdf

Comment: Are you importing `geometry` twice?

Answer (score 398, accepted):

Here's a non-exhaustive list of possibilities for "nice" font families – which I take to mean that they provide both text and math fonts – for use with `pdflatex`.

---

- **Computer Modern** – the default font family for TeX and LaTeX, i.e., the font family that's used if no other font family is loaded.

  The following image represents the output of the MWE listed at the end of this posting using the Computer Modern fonts. (All subsequent images use the same MWE but load one or more additional font-related packages.)

  > [image]

---

- **lmodern** – Latin Modern. Very much like Computer Modern, but with many more glyphs, e.g., for characters with accents, cedillas, ogoneks, etc. Very useful if the language you write your documents in isn't English (which has, of course, very little need for these additional glyphs).

  If the following image strikes you as near-identical to the one above, that's of course no accident, given the close dependence of the Latin Modern fonts on the Computer modern fonts. (*Hint*: When comparing the two images, look closely at the word "Let" that starts the theorem's statements. In this word, the space between the "e" and the t" is ever so slightly wider for CM than it is for LM. I was able to detect this difference only by switching back and forth rapidly between the two images. To detect any more-significant differences between the two fonts, it's probably necessary to display various accented characters.)

  > [image]

---

- **mathpazo** – based on Hermann Zapf's Palatino font

  > [image]

---

- Addendum, 2017/02/11: **newpxtext** and **newpxmath** – also based on Zapf's Palatino font. The packages are based on (and constitute noticeable improvements) on Young Ryu's older `pxfonts` font package. Comparing the screenshots below and above, you should notice the larger summation and integral symbols generated by the `newpxmath` package.

  > [image]

---

- **kpfonts** – "Kepler" fonts. A very nice set of fonts, based originally on Palatino, but highly evolved and outfitted with many special features. Global options for upright and slanted Greek math-mode characters, oldstyle numerals, and options to load lots of quaint (i.e., archaic) glyphs including the historic long-s. Comparing the result of the MWE compiled with the `kpfonts` and `mathpazo` packages, some important differences are immediately visible when looking at the integral and sum symbols and lowercase Greek letters such as `\gamma`.

  > [image]

---

- **mathptmx** – based on the `Times Roman` font. Times Roman (and its close cousin, Times New Roman) must surely among the world's most ubiquitous fonts. Whether that's an advantage (or not...) will depend importantly on your sense of aesthetics.

  > [image]

---

- The math alphabet that comes with the `mathptmx` package is passable, but if you really want good-looking mathematics in Times Roman, consider purchasing the [**MathTime Pro 2**](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) package. This commercial package, which provides only math-mode fonts, provides *optically scaled small glyphs* for use in first- and second-level sub- and superscripts, good-looking *large operator symbols* (sums, integrals, ...), as well as many other goodies. Notice, in particular, the shapes of the integral and summation symbols in the following screenshot.

  > [image]

---

- Addendum, 2014/03/13: The **stix** font package provides yet another Times clone; the following uses v1.1.0 of the stix fonts, package date 2012/12/23. The shape of the summation symbol is clearly quite close to that of the `mathptmx` package shown above, and not particularly similar to that of the `mtpro2`, `txfonts` or `newtxmath` fonts (see below). The integral symbol provided by the `stix` package quite slanted, as well as quite tall.

  > [image]

---

- **txfonts** – another package based on Times Roman, by Young Ryu. It's been around for more than a decade. Its glyph shapes are pleasing but the font suffers from inconsistent font metrics that can cause collisions between adjacent letters. Observe in particular the shape of the integral symbol: Its shape is very different from that provided by the `mathptmx` and `mtpro2` packages (or, for that matter, the Computer/Latin Modern font families) and is, instead, quite similar to the shape provided by the `kpfonts` package.

  > [image]

---

- Starting in the first half of 2012, the `txfonts` package has been revised and improved considerably. The new version, by Michael Sharpe, is called **newtx**. It's a [package](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/fonts/newtx/) with two sub-packages – `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`. The `newtxtext` package loads clones of Helvetica and of a monospaced font to provide reasonably well matched sans-serif and "typewriter" fonts.

  > [image]

---

- The **Linux Libertine** font family, to be loaded via the [libertine](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine-legacy) package. If you like this text font and wish to employ it with the `newtxmath` package, be sure to load the `newtxmath` package with the `libertine` option; doing so will set up a special set of math-mode fonts that is meant to harmonize well with the Libertine text fonts.

  > [image]
- (Addendum 2019/11/28) The **Linux Libertine** font family, to be loaded via the [libertine](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine-legacy) package, along with the [libertinust1math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertinust1math) math font package. (Many thanks to [@campa](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/82917/campa) for bringing the **Libertinus T1 Math package** to my attention.) Overall, the "look" created by this math font family is very similar to that produced by loading the `newtxmath` package with the option `libertine`; this is not surprising, given that the same person (the incomparable Michael Sharpe) produced both the `newtxmath` and the `libertinust1math` package (as well as many other font packages!).

  > [image]

---

- **Addendum**, 7 Feb 2013: Upon the request of @mforbes (see also his/her [separate answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97128/5001)), I'm reproducing here the output of the MWE if one uses the **Palatino *text* font** together with the **AMS Euler (eulervm) *math* font**. Since both fonts were designed by the same person (Hermann Zapf!), it's not a coincidence that they work together rather well. Note also that because the "Euler" fonts have an upright rather than slanted appearance, the text part of the Residue Theorem's statement is set in upright letters rather than in italics.

  > [image]

---

As I noted at the very beginning of this answer, this list is by no means intended to be exhaustive. Nevertheless, I hope it'll give you a good start if you need to choose a set of fonts.

There are, of course, many other font packages, most of which provide "only" text-mode fonts. Among these are the "TeX-Gyre" font families `Termes` (a Times Roman clone), `Pagella` (a Palatino clone), and `Schola` (a Century Schoolbook clone); one would load the packages `tgtermes`, `tgpagella`, and `tgschola`, respectively, to access these fonts. However, as these are text fonts, you still need to choose a suitable math font.

---

Here's the code that generated the images showing the residue theorem. Be sure to un-comment the appropriate font-related `\usepackage` statements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}

%% Choose one of the following (if not choosing the  
%% default, viz., Computer Modern, font family):
 %\usepackage{lmodern}
 %%
 %\usepackage{mathpazo}
 %\usepackage[theoremfont]{newpxmath} \usepackage{newpxmath}
 %\usepackage{kpfonts}
 %%
 %\usepackage{mathptmx}
 %\usepackage{times,mtpro2}
 \usepackage{stix}
 %\usepackage{txfonts}
 %\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
 %%
 %\usepackage{libertine} \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
 \usepackage{libertine,libertinust1math} % added 2019/11/28
 %%
 %\usepackage{newpxtext} \usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{theorem}[Residue Theorem]
Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated 
singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed 
rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the 
points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\! f = \sum_{k=1}^m 
  n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

*Addendum*, 2012/06/15 – A personal note: the upvotes on this answer earned me, earlier today, my 100th "badge" from TeX.SE. What a great site! You, fellow users, readers, and contributors to TeX.SE, are the one that make it great! Many thanks to all of you.

Comment: Congratulations on the occasion of a `Great Answer` gold badge `:-)`.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Thanks so much! I very much appreciate your best wishes.

Comment: I happened (accidentally) to visit your profile today and saw 99 votes and I didn't upvote that nice answer so far!. Very bad on my part. I am priviledged to cast the 100th vote for a nice fellow friend. Keep up the good work Mico.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Even more thanks, then!! :-)

Comment: What do you think about the 'charter' font? Why is it not listed? I always thought it is most famous afther cm.

Comment: @adam - Note that I started my answer with "Here's a *non-exhaustive list* of..." [emphasis added]. :-) I'm in no position to judge objectively which fonts are "most famous" or are used most frequently, but based on casual empiricism I would have guessed that Times Roman is the single most frequently used (and abused!) font. What math font would you suggest should be combined with `charter`: `Math Design`, or something else?

Comment: I am switching all my files to use kpfonts. Very nice font!

Comment: @MICO -- STIX 2.0, currently under development, has moved quite a bit beyond being a mere Times clone. Tiro Typeworks [http://www.tiro.com] has subtly modified the shapes to make the font far more useful both for printing and e-viewing. (I am an AMS employee. The AMS is a part of STIPUB [http://www.stixfonts.org/stipubs.html] which sponsors the STIX fonts. A number of problems with STIX 1.0 have also been fixed.

Comment: @sgmoye - Many thanks for this information. I look forward to version 2.0 of the STIX font family.

Comment: mathtime seems to be very similar to mathpazo. Can you detect any difference? And, do you prefer mathpazo or kpfonts? (for writing equations and having good kerning)

Comment: @skan - I'm a bit puzzled by your claim that `mathtime` (a Times Roman clone) looks "very similar" to `mathpazo` (a Palatino clone); speaking for myself, I can certainly detect *lots* of differences. Regarding `mathpazo` vs `kpfonts`: they're both Palatino clones, and their text-mode glyphs are therefore (unsurprisingly) rather similar. The `kpfonts` package offers quite a few additional options in terms of upright and slanted Greek lowercase and uppercase letters. You may (or may not...) prefer the large `\sum` and `\int` symbols provided by `kpfonts`.

Comment: Is there any option in kpfonts to get an integral or sum like the mathtime ones? (smaller and tilted, italic-like)

Comment: @skan - May I ask that you post a *new query* to raise the issue you're looking to solve? That way, your question will be seen by many more people. Thanks.

Comment: I've read kpfonts are incompatbile with fontspec's LuaTeX, What can I do or what alternatives are there?

Comment: @skan - Your question is unclear. LuaTeX does not belong to `fontspec`. Are you using LuaLaTeX? Are you interested in the Palatino font family for text and math?

Comment: @Mico, I'm looking for a nice math font, preferably opentype, and a text working well with kerning and advanced mycrotype options, preferably similar to Palatino (it's an imposition of my university).

Comment: @Mico, What opentype font do you suggest for math? . You didn't say anything about Xits or Pagella.

Comment: @skan - Unfortunately, the class of Opentype math fonts is not yet as stable and robust as Computer/Latin Modern is under pdfLaTeX. If you're limited to Palatino clones, you may want to look into TeX Gyre Pagella for text and TeX Gyre Pagella Math for math. I assume you're familiar with [this website](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math). XITS and Stix are Times Roman clones, so they probably don't cut it for you. [Asana Math](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/Asana-Math/) is sort of a Garalde and may thus also be of interest to you.

Comment: Would you suggest "TeX Gyre Pagella" or NewPX fonts?. I need a Palatino clone but only for the text part. For math I think my university won't check it. I could try to use different fonts for text and for math, but I don't know if this may cause problems.

Comment: @skan - It depends on whether you use pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. If it's the former, `newpxtext` and `newpxmath` should do just fine -- and almost certainly much better than either `pxfonts` or `mathpazo`. I have no idea how well (or even if!) any of these packages work under LuaLaTeX. Unless your document has very little math to begin with -- in which case it probably doesn't matter anyway -- I would like to discourage you from mixing Palatino text and non-Palatino math material. The differences will just be too jarring, even to people who don't know much about fonts to begin with.

Comment: @Mico I would like to use LuaTeX

Comment: @skan - I'm puzzled, then, why you keep referring to font packages that aren't suitable for use under LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Maybe because I don't know anything about fonts. Anyway if you read my previous messages you'll see I'm interested in LuaTeX compatible fonts from the beginning

Comment: What do you thing about this comment? "The opentype fonts in newpx appear to be opentype wrappers for the type 1 fonts, still in legacy TeX 8bit encoding, not Unicode fonts with an OpenType MATH table, so they are not OpenType math fonts in the sense that is required here. (Unless I missed a new font with a Math table?)" https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/373#issuecomment-278609091

Comment: @skan - Thanks for this. I'm afraid I know very little about the actual mechanics of font encodings. I'm thus not in a position to say anything useful on this topic. Sorry.

Comment: Michael Sharpe improved another Young Ryu's font, pxfont with newpx.  This one is based on Palatino.  It is maybe worth adding that to your valuable list.

Comment: @Pygmalion - Thanks for this suggestion; I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Your answer shows a couple of Times variant where you say that the summation symbol does not look similar to mtpro2. However, the pictures show a symbol nearly identical to that font. Is there an error in the pictures?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto -- Thanks for contacting me in this matter. I actually agree with your assessment! Specifically, I went through the Times Roman font examples; indeed, the screenshots for the `txfonts` and `stix` package weren't correct. (About a year ago, this site had a major meltdown of sorts, and all kinds of links were compromised and not rebuilt correctly. All I can surmise at the moment is that this problem affected my posting as well.) I've posted new screenshots for those two font packages. Hopefully, the other images are OK -- at least until the next meltdown...

Comment: @Mico, great, thank you! This abundance of Times fonts always gives me a headache. I think once I read somewhere that one of those should be the "preferred" one, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 40):

Here is one combination omitted by Mico that I use extensively:
[mathpazo](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo) for text (based on [Palatino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatino)) and [AMS Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler) ([eulervm](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eulervm)) for math:

[image: Palatino (mathpazo) with Euler (eulervm) for math.]

Both fonts were designed by [Hermann Zapf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Zapf) and harmonize quite well together.  Since they are freely available, I can also use this for papers on http://arXiv.org for example.  They are not quite so space efficient as other combinations (Minion Pro + [AMS Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler) works well for this purpose), but I find are much easier to read – especially on screen – than many of the other combinations (esp. the * Modern and Times based fonts.)

As [AMS Euler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler) is an upright math font, it does not look very nice when inserted in the midst of extended italic text.  As a result, I felt it necessary to restyle the theorem environment somewhat to use roman text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}   % With old-style figures and real smallcaps.
\linespread{1.025}              % Palatino leads a little more leading

% Euler for math and numbers
\usepackage[euler-digits,small]{eulervm}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\hbar}{\hslash}}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

% No easy way of putting the theorem description in italics?
% It seems I need to define a new style...
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% 
   {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}% 
   {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ \textit{(##3)}\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}

\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{theorem}[Residue Theorem]
Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated 
singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed 
rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the 
points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\! f = \sum_{k=1}^m 
  n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've always wondered what is the reason for italic/slanted text in theorems?

Comment: @morbusg You need to know where exactly the Theorem ends and possible comments start.

Comment: One should include a symbol, or a blank line, or some sort of signal to indicate the end of the theorem if not using italics, or indentation. (Or maybe demand that theorem statements etc. be a single paragraph long.)

Comment: As of 2020, there is an updated package for this based on `newpxmath` and `eulervm`: the `eulerpx` package.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks!  I will look into it, but there seem to be some [issues with small-caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504425/6903) in `newpxtext` - not sure if there are any issues with `newpxmath`.  Maybe one can combine `mathpazo` for text with `eulerpx` for math. Would also be nice to have support for the [`varvw` option from `newtxmath`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341301/6903).

Comment: Could you explain what the `small` option for eulervm does?

Comment: @Richard From [the docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/eulervm/doc/latex/eulervm/eulervm.pdf): "causes the Euler fonts to be loaded at 95% of their nominal size, thus blending better with certain text font families, for instance Aldus or Minion." This is a matter of your own aesthetic: try with and without to see which size produces a better balance in your work.

Comment: @mforbes thanks!

Answer (score 34):

here you'll find the "Survey of Free Math Fonts for TeX and LaTeX"

http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf

Comment: it's a bit out of date, though.  since then, we've gained newtx (at least) among type 1 fonts, and at least 4 free open type maths fonts.  the uk faq is similarly out of date...

Answer (score 26):

If you do not have the Adobe reader installed, locate a copy for your operating system and install it. Locate the directory where the `MinionPro` fonts are installed and copy them to a temp-directory.

Direct you browser to [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro) and read the `README` on how to install the MinionPro` font for LaTeX. If this package does not work, you may try the original package you will find at [this directory at CTAN](http://ftp.fagskolen.gjovik.no/pub/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/README).

Read the documentation for the MinionPro package. Add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[footnotefigures]{MinionPro}
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
\renewcommand{\scdefault}{ssc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{luximono} % Monospace font
\usepackage[letterspace=160,babel=true,tracking=true,kerning=true]{microtype}
```

Then you can start using one of the most beautiful fonts made. In my documents (agreement, memos, legal opinions, etc.), I do not use any sans serif fonts (neither any boldface). Have look at the package [classicthesis](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/classicthesis) to get tips on how to compose nice looking documents.

Her is Mico’s MWE using MinionPro:

[image]

Comment: If the original MinionPro package does not work for you, you can try the updated version by me: [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro). You have to generate the metrics yourself, though (also done by the script, see the README).

Comment: The `letterspace`/`tracking` option of the microtype package stretches sc-shaped text too much. I noticed this as I used `\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}`

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt What is too much or too little depends on taste. `microtype`offer you the possibility to define your own stretch.

Answer (score 25):

## `Cochineal`, `newtxtt`, and `Cabin`, with `newtxmath`

Cochineal is a serif font based on the free font Crimson. In this example I've used settings given by the packages' vignettes, with scale modifications of my own.

```
\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal}
\usepackage[scale=.95,type1]{cabin}
\usepackage[cochineal,bigdelims,cmintegrals,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[zerostyle=c,scaled=.94]{newtxtt}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}
```

[image: Imgur]

### `garamondx`, `zlmtt`, and `Source Sans Pro` with `newtxmath`

Here are two options using `garamondx`, which is free but not included in texlive out-of-the-box, although I think it might be available in MikTeX. It has to be downloaded separately if you're running texlive, which the [`getnonfreefonts`](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) program will do for you.

The first option also uses a modified version of the Latin Modern typewriter font, and Source Sand pro for serif.

```
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[scaled=1.01]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\useosf
```

[image: Imgur]

### `garamondx`, `inconsolata`, and `Fira Sans` with `mathdesign`

Here, Inconsolata is used as the monospace font option with Fira Sans as the sans-serif font.

```
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[varqu,varl,var0,scaled=0.97]{inconsolata}
\usepackage{FiraSans}
```

[image: Imgur]

### Update

I revised this answer to include solutions that showcased serif, mono-space, and sans-serif solutions (which is what was originally asked for).

Comment: What opentype font package do you suggest?. Including math and Platino-like text. I want to use it with Luatex and use kerning and protrusion.

Comment: the first package option works very well. I like Crimson and EB Garamond very much, but the second and third do not work in my Texmaker, does it mean I have to download garamondx manually first?

Comment: @FinleyHuaxin, yes, but use the freely available `ebgaramond` package instead. Instead of the first three `\usepackage` lines, use the single `\usepackage[ebgaramond]{newtx}` line.

Answer (score 16):

I really like [Bitstream Charter](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/charter/charter.pdf). It has been designed for low-resolution laser printers and is very readable but still good looking. It has been donated by Bitstream to the X Consortium and is thus freely available (`\usepackage{charter}`, [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/charter)). It does not contain real small caps though.

[Charis SIL](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=CharisSILfont) is a free derivate that provides more glyphs. 
There is still a commercial version of Charter that contains small caps, ranging figures and additional glyphs.

Comment: You can get math support with `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}`, by the way.

Comment: It should be noted that various glyphs in that font don't look to good. For example some of the blackboard bold letters (`\mathbb M` for example - if I recall correctly), the spacing around `$f$` isn't too good either and `\left\langle foo \middle\vert bar \right\rangle` makes the middle bar the wrong height when `foo` and `bar` are too high.

Comment: And there is also `\usepackage{XCharter}` which offers many features (like small caps).

Comment: @Manuel Very helpful comment, thank you. Am using it right now, works flawlessly with a little bit of googling / tricking.

Comment: I second this answer. Since it has lots of vertical lines, less hinting seems to be required, thus improving screen legibility, which is what the original question was about.

Answer (score 8):

## `mathastext`

Another option is to use Jean-François Burnol's [`mathastext`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) which adopts some of the letters and symbols in the document's font (or any other) for use in math environments.

### with `fbb`

Here is an example using `mathastext` with Michael Sharpe's great [`fbb`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fbb/) package (an expanded version of Bembo/Cardo), together with `newtxmath` using the libertine option.

```
\usepackage{fbb}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath} 
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}
\MTsetmathskips{f}{5mu}{1mu} # add space to compensate for the large f-italic in fbb
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: There is now the `ETbb` package instead of `fbb`.

Answer (score 5):

Many font packages will get listed within the answers to this question.  So, instead of just adding another single "answer" with another single font package, here's a list of 30 Staple Fonts that cover the most popular Font Styles in common use, such as **Garamond**, **Century**, **Charter**, **Palitino**, **Times**, **Libertine**, **Bookman**, **Utopia** and **Helvetica**.

The code at the bottom would amount to a "font section" of a LaTeX Preamble, use it as a Template.  You'd need to comment out every Serif (Roman) font except ONE, and also every Sans Serif font except ONE.  The color effects of having the font packages stand out shows the package names well, with a description grayed out to make it more noticeable.

**The LaTeX Font Catalogue** is an excellent resource, but I've weeded through them for the packages with the most style glyphs of each variety (the most style options such as smallcaps, smallcaps bold, smallcaps italics etc.) and included just those of most popular fonts.

ALSO included are the VERY basic PSNFSS fonts.  Those are fonts that every TeX user should be aware of, because they are included in Every Minimal TeX Installation, and will run on Every postscript printer even without embedding.  So, popularity, availability, comparability with postscript printers, and expansive style assortment of the font were my basic criteria.

I keep these 30 in my Basic LaTeX Template, because of that.  Also, note at the very start of the code below, I change the Computer Modern font family (Obsolete) to the Latin Modern.  If no font packages are used, you will atleast get the benefits of [T1] font encoding.  For the benefit of LaTeX users that find this tread like I did, by searching the internet, you should know that Computer Modern remains the default for TeX distributions only so that LaTeX documents created years ago, will look and process exactly the same.

```
%%%%     FONTS PACKAGE OPTIONS in the Preamble  %                        
%%%%     always replace default Computer Modern with Latin Modern [T1] encoding:
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} % MONO Latin Modern Font % T1 encoding of cmtt font style  
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lmr} % SERIF Latin Modern Font % T1 encoding of cmr font style
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss} % SANS Latin Modern Font % T1 encoding of cmss font style
%  %  %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   % 
%  %  % PSNFSS \ssfamily fonts (SANS)
\usepackage{helvet} % PSNFSS Font, in every TeX distribution 
\usepackage{avant}  % PSNFSS Font, in every TeX distribution 
%  %  % Extended \ssfamily (Sans) fonts; load extraFonts option from TeX                    
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{berasans}% package has a handy scaling option
\usepackage{libris}   % a nice, almost handwritten calligraphic look
\usepackage{biolinum} % included with the {Libertine} font package
\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage{paratype} 
%%%  END OF SANS SERIF FONT PACKAGES 
%  %  %  %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %
%  %  % PSNFSS \rmfamily fonts (SERIF) 
\usepackage{mathptmx}  % Times % PSNFSS Font, in every TeX distribution %
\usepackage{charter}   % Bitstream Charter % PSNFSS Font, in every TeX distribution %
\usepackage{mathpazo}  % Palatino % PSNFSS Font, in every TeX distribution 
\usepackage{bookman}   % Bookman % PSNFSS Font in every TeX
\usepackage{chancery}  % Zapf Chancery % PSNFSS Font in every TeX, a Calligraphic Font
\usepackage{newcent}   % New Century Schoolbook % PSNFSS Font in every TeX distribution % To replace it's Avant Garde sans add this:% \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{xxx}
%  %  % Extended \rmfamily (SERIF) fonts; load extraFonts option from TeX
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{beraserif}% package has a handy scaling option
\usepackage{XCharter} % Bitstream's Charter extended with many style varieties 
\usepackage{fouriernc}% Century Schoolbook % compact and lighter than New Century Schoolbook 
\usepackage{tgschola} % TeX Gyre Schola, New Century Schoolbook with many font style varieties 
\usepackage{tgtermes} % TeX Gyre Termes, Times with many font style varieties 
\usepackage{tgbonum}  % TeX Gyre Bonum, Bookman with many font style varieties 
\usepackage{tgpagella}% TeX Gyre Pagello, a Palatino font with many font style varieties 
\usepackage{fourier}  % Utopia, package {utopia} is obsolete
\usepackage{txfonts}  % TX Serif and Sans (Helvetica)
\usepackage{kpfonts}  % KP Serif and Sans, large variety of font styles
\usepackage{libertine}% Libertine + Linux Biolinum (Extra TeXLive fonts) 
\usepackage{fbb}      % A Garamond Font (Bembo) with many font styles
%%% END SERIF FONTS
%%% NOTE!!! Be sure to comment out all but ONE Serif and ONE Sans
%%% from the package selections above.
%  %  %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %
%  %  %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   %   % 
%  %  % Load Math Support if necessary
%
\usepackage[myFontPackage]{mathdesign}
%
%
%%% END OF FONTS In the Preamble 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: What should this be useful for in this question? I don't see the purpose of listing zillions of font packages.

Comment: It's 30 staple font packages for a Basic LaTeX template, easily commented in or out, good to have handy because: 1> They are PSNFSS postscript fonts that all postscript printer can read without embedding, and always included with every TeX distributions,  [OR]  2> They are easily added by installing the optional [FULL] TeX Font Collection and have an extraordinary range of styles, such as SmallCaps, SmallCaps BOLD, SmallCaps italics, or [scaling = x] options.  It's extremely useful to keep them in a basic LaTeX template so that you don't have to weed through The LaTeX Font Catalouge's lessers.

Comment: Also, it's most Space Efficient on Stack Exchange to include information in One Post, that would otherwise take 30 separate posts, for 30 fantastic font packages.

Comment: Well, the problem with this question is that it sort-of predates the time when this type of questions were considered OK. Now, they are not ok, and if someone asked this question today, I would vote to close it very likely. It's difficult to justify a new answer to a question that would be closed by today's standards... Also, at least half of the packages you list is either obsolete or awful, some of them provide just different versions of the same font etc.

Comment: That's false.  The only ones that are considered obsolete are the ones included in every minimal TeX installation, and are mentioned for that reason, and explained in my post.

Comment: A link to the LaTeX font catalogue would accomplish much the same goal.

Comment: But the catalogue lists Hundreds of font packages, many obsolete versions of far better extended ones repetitively listed. Also, this short list includes some not there, for instance Avant Guarde and the classic sans serif "Helvetica" font.  These are much better for a Basic LaTeX Template than listing nearly every font available under the sun, and leaving some important ones out.

Comment: The usefulness of your list would improve if you (a) stated which fonts are pure text fonts and which ones are text+math fonts, (b) grouped the fonts wherever possible, e.g. to indicate that the `mathptmx`, `txfonts`, and `tgtermes` packages all provide Times Roman clones, and (c) gave a minimal example (one line, or even one sentence, such as "The quick brown fox...") of each font you keep in the list, as a visual guide for readers who may not have the foggiest idea of what, e.g., `New Century Schoolbook` looks like.

Comment: I also get the impression from your list that many of the packages are quite outdated, and I spot some redundancy. What's the purpose of included both `mathptmx` and `tgtermes`? The latter is an extension of the former. I'd also like to know the basis for concluding which fonts are "popular". I don't see one of my favorite fonts on this list, and I can't say I see `fbb` nearly as often as some other fonts I don't see here.

Comment: I'm making a modification to the list based on the comments.  mathptmx is a universal PSNFSS font, within every minimal TeX distribution, works without embedding on any postscript printer.  tgtermes has additional font styles and glyphs.  I'm going to make modifications to improve the list

Comment: Recall the OP's initial statement: "My goal is to choose a 'nice' font family (serif, sans serif, monospace, and 'math') for my basic LaTeX template." `Zapf Chancery` may not be suitable for a "basic LaTeX template", is it? A separate issue: the x-heights of some of the sans-serifs you list starkly exceed the x-heights of some the serifs; take, say, `avant` and `fbb`. Can you suggest some adjustments a user should make in order to make the fonts harmonize even just a little bit?

Comment: I think is the perfect choice in a very specific case, as an inset that replicates a small letter or handwriting.  Perhaps the main font is Sans Serif, and there are minipages from a notable letter.  But, I'd advise no one to use `Zaph Chancery` for more than a small inset though.  No, every Sans is not intended to be used with every Roman. I'm going to work on a little "harmony" adjustments.  `txfonts`, `Libertine` `kpfonts` have good harmony, with paired Sans with Roman fonts.  Also, `mathpazo` (easy reading) and `mathptmx` (compact readability) from PSFNSS are available to every TeX user

Comment: What opentype font package do you suggest?. Including math and Platino-like text. I want to use it with Luatex and use kerning and protrusion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned (I am a mathematician), the most important feature of a math font is readability. All the packages that provide sanserif fonts in math have serious readability problems: some letters and symbols are difficult to distinguish from each other. In my experience, the `arev` and `euler` packages have the most serious problems.  The `\nu` and `v` or `\rho` and `p` are barely distinguishable, and in case of `arev` even the `\alpha` and `a` are difficult to tell apart.  Here is a file to experiment with.  It also has the packages which I think give the best (most readable) text-math font combinations.

```
 \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

% Sans serif math, each with issues of readibility
\usepackage{arev}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{sfmath}
%\usepackage[math]{kurier}
%\usepackage[math]{iwona}
%\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}



% Good (IMO) Serif math fonts
% \usepackage[utopia,expert]{mathdesign}
% \usepackage[ebgaramond, expert]{mathdesign}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
% \usepackage{kpfonts}

% I personally like this text-math combination the most
% \usepackage[utopia,expert]{mathdesign}
% \usepackage{venturis}

% This has best \gamma, but \rho^p is not acceptable IMO
% \usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \mathsf{a}&=\alpha\\
  \rho&=p\\
  \rho^p&=p^\rho\\
  v&=\nu\\
  v^\nu&=\nu^v\\
  \gamma^\nu&=\nu^\gamma\\
  \Lambda&=\wedge
\end{align}
 
\end{document}
```

Here is what we get in case of `arev`

[image: arev]

and here is what we get with `mathpazo` (which has the best, immediately recognizable `alpha` and the `v` and `\nu` and easy to distinguish)

[image: mathpazo]