# Choosing a font for a thesis

Tags: fonts

I'm working on my thesis and I don't really know what font is the best choice for thesis work. I'm really convinced of only one thing: I don't want to use Times New Roman. First I checked on the latex fonts catalogue but there are too many fonts available. Which fonts do you think are the best for a thesis? I'm using `eulervm` for maths and I like it so much, but for simple text?

Comment: This isn't really a question about LaTeX. I suggest you ask this question at _Academia Beta-Stack Exchange_.

Comment: You might want to have a look at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1576/5701

Comment: Have a look at `classicthesis` which offers a beautiful template. The default font is Palatino, but my favourite(s) at the moment are Minion Pro or Adobe Sabon (both commericial). A very, nice and very complete font is Linux Libertine. KP Fonts is also nice.

Comment: For this purpose I created a [short list of fonts](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7nop90r0ste9f4r/shortfontlist.pdf). Also check out [the community poll about font usage](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1576/17484). The problem with this kind of question is that nobody will agree what good fonts are. The KP fonts don't appear in my list for example.

Comment: Your main concern is going to be how it looks printed, right? So, I would *strongly* suggest you try out `charter`. Simply add `\usepackage{charter}` and be amazed!

Comment: Just one more comment. Do your readers a favour and choose a seriffed typeface for themain text.

Comment: @recluze: Charter looks good. But my math fonts in the text looks thinner!

Comment: You find an answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math