# Change Font Weight in Math Mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode

I would like to change the font "thickness" of the font in math mode. I already tried to find a similar method like \DeclareMathSizes but i didn't find something.

edit:
I want to use - if possible - in math mode a font with serifs that is not as thin as the "typical" one. Since I'm trying to include latex formulas in powerpoint I need them for a presentation and, thus, a thicker font would be great.
P.S.: To the best of my knowledge, I'm using pdflatex ;-)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on what you're looking to achieve. E.g., do you want "bold" to be the default math style? Finally, please indicate whether you're using pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or some other TeX engine/format.

Comment: @Mico, thanks, I made an edit. I hope its now a bit clearer

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your objectives. It looks like you should probably change both the text-mode and math-mode fonts. There are quite a few font families out there that may meet your needs. Have a look at [Suggest a nice font family for my basic LaTeX template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59706/5001) to get you started.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With standard fonts you can switch to bold mathematics via `\mathversion{bold}`:

[image: Sample bold switching]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

A mathematical test \( E = mc^2 \) and \( \int_0^1 \alpha(t)\,dt =
2\pi/3 \).  Here something that is already bold \(
\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y} = 1 \).

\mathversion{bold}

A mathematical test \( E = mc^2 \) and \( \int_0^1 \alpha(t)\,dt =
2\pi/3 \).  Here something that is already bold \(
\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y} = 1 \).

\end{document}
```

Alternatively consider using a different font set-up.  One is provided by the `fourier` package:

[image: Sample fourier]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

A mathematical test \( E = mc^2 \) and \( \int_0^1 \alpha(t)\,dt =
2\pi/3 \).  Here something that is already bold \(
\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y} = 1 \).

\end{document}
```

Have a look at the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) for samples of other fonts with math support.

Comment: Note that with `\mathversion{bold}` the font style, i.e., **italics, is preserved,** whereas with `\mathbf` the font is in **normal style (straight)**. That makes using the first method not really equivalent to using the second one.