# Common fonts used in writing a thesis in Mathematics

Tags: fonts, thesis

I am writing my thesis in Mathematics but I am not happy with the default fonts of the template that I am using. So kindly inform me what are the common fonts used in thesis along with the latex commands for those fonts.

Comment: I like Charter with Utopia math, and with Bera mono font. `\usepackage{utopia}\usepackage{XCharter}\usepackage{beramono}` with the correct scalings, which I don't remember.

Comment: I suggest you peruse the following posting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5001.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this combination:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}%  for math    
\usepackage{libertine}%  serif and sans serif
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}%% mono
```

Answer (score 3):

I use this combination with LuaLaTeX.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Biolinum O Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin,num,Greek,greek}]{Linux Biolinum O Bold}
\setmathfont[range={\mathrm,0048-0057}]{Linux Biolinum O}
```

[image]