# kpfonts: no errors, no warnings but no PDF

Tags: kpfonts

I just installed `kpfonts` via MikTex Package Manager. 
I tried to reproduce the following example which is taken from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{theorem}[Residue Theorem]
Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated 
singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed 
rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the 
points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\! f = \sum_{k=1}^m 
  n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

It runs fine with, say, `mathpazo`, but when I compile with `kpfonts` it opens my PDF viewer, but it doesn't show the file and it actually doesn't produce any, that is there is no `.pdf` in my working  dictionary. There are no errors or warnings either. Don't get it.

Comment: What does the .log say? Did you install the fonts `as administrator`? Jst in case, run ̉`updmap --sys` from the command line (as administrator).

Comment: I forgot: Welcome to TSX!

Comment: You probably have user map files. After a font installation your must update them by running `updmap` in a command line (as user not as admin).