# How to format paper for research article?

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I'm new to LaTeX, and am having trouble figuring out how to format my paper so that I'll have two columns of text. I also have some figures, which I'm including using `\includegraphics[width=..]{file}` statement. I've searched around on here but nothing I've seen has worked. I'm using texmaker editor and miktex if that makes a difference. I'd also like to have nice looking font, which I've also had no luck with. Any suggestions would be really appreciated

Comment: With `\twocolumn` you can start a new two column page, or for even more columns an options, [the multicol package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol?lang=de). For a font to use with pdfTeX, have a look at [the LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: For font ideas, see the posting [Suggest a “nice” font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5001)

Comment: Use the twocolumn option, e.g \documentclass[twocolumn]{article}.  The most common font for academic text is some form of Times Roman.  The default gives you that.  Also try tgtermes in combination with mtpro2 and look into microtype.  If you're doing lots of math then amsmath packages will be helpful.

Comment: Where do you publish your article?  A special journal? Ask them for their template you then have to use!  If the journal provides an own template do not change the layout, they will not use your changings.

Comment: My suggestion: Now invest time in learn the very basics. Meanwhile try to be productive only with already made and working templates (there are many in places like latextemplates.com or sharelaetx.com) that do need layout changes,  or use the LyX editor to make documents from the scratch.