# Change only ONE character in Latex template

Tags: math-mode, templates, characters

I have a book template of Elsevier for which in the math environment the character "v" looks very similar to greek \nu. This causes a lot of misunderstanding and frustration for the readers. I have tried the txfonts package and it solves the problem. Here are the outputs
[image]

Since the book is already finished and I cannot replace all the "v" characters with \varv

***MY QUESTION IS***:
Is there any way that I can change the "v" letter with \varv in the Latex template that I have? This will be a lifesaver.

Comment: What font package are you using? Is it `mathptmx`?

Comment: @egreg
On the main file it reads:
\documentclass[book,numbers]{elsbook-A07b}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm,makeidx,graphicx}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{helvet}

Comment: Another option is to import `\nu` from Computer Modern. See the middle two lines of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435722/98394.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just change the `\mathcode` of `v`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`v=\varv}

\begin{document}

A `v' in math: $v$

A `nu' in math: $\nu$

\end{document}
```

### Output with the `\AtBeginDocument` line commented out

[image]

### Output with the `\AtBeginDocument` line uncommented

[image]

### Comments

I'd suggest using

```
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}
```

instead of `\usepackage{txfonts}`. The fonts are essentially the same, but the defects of `txfonts` are straightened off.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

A `v' in math: $v$

A `nu' in math: $\nu$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It solved the issue. Should I use \AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`v=\varv} for the case that you suggested in the comments?

Comment: @AminR. No, with `newtx`, you just pass the option `varvw` (that also changes the `w` to be similar to `v`).

Comment: it complains that: 'varvw' undefined in families 'ntxmath'.

Comment: @AminR. Update your TeX distribution. The option was added in October 2016.

Answer (score 9):

Supposing you are using:

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

The following in your preamble replaces your 'v's in mathmode with the `\varv` symbol in the output.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathord}{lettersA}{51}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareMathSymbol{v}{\mathord}{lettersA}{51}
\begin{document}

This is \verb+\varv+ $\varv$

This is v $v$.

This is greek \verb+\nu+ $\nu$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As @egreg noticed, the `[varvw]` option to `newtxmath` does that also. You are never too old to learn something new.