# Import a single letter from a different font (and use it in text mode)

Tags: fonts, characters

There are many questions about import symbols form other packages to use them in math mode. But there is nothing about import symbols (letters) from other font families and use them in the text.

In particular, I was wondering if I can import single character to use it in a particular shape. For example, if I can import the italic z from `Times New Roman` and use it with the `TeX Gyre Termes` font. Or another example: I don't like the `italic` f from the `millennial` `package` and I want to replace it from the `italic` f of `computer modern` font. In this case I would also replace the symbols fi, ff and ffi to get the correct `ligatures`.

My question is: is it possible? For example, from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341299/change-only-one-character-in-latex-template) I know I can change the z used in the `math` `mode` with the code `\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode'v=\varv}`. Is there something similar for text? For example something like `\AtBeginDocument{\textitaliccode'z=\varz}`?

Thanks

Comment: It is possible to make “combo fonts” with LuaTeX.

Comment: in luatex yes as you can make virtual fonts on the fly but for classic tex or xetex, you would need to make a virtual font from the two base fonts, otherwise any code would be equivalent to `\textsf{z}oo` but the font change woul dbreak any inter-letter kerns and disable hyphenation.

Comment: You say `LuaTeX`. Is the same option avaible for `LuaLaTeX`? I say this because I suppose it would be closer to the usual `pdfLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371647/call-a-luatex-combo-font-through-nfss

Comment: yes font access is a feature of the engine, not the macro package.

Comment: There are a few packages that define virtual fonts, but in practical use, you'd probably do something like `\DeclareRobustCommand\itz{{\timesfamily\itshape z}}`.

Comment: @Davislor I would like to write simply z, without any command like you say. Would it be possible?

Comment: @Dog_69 See Ulrike Fischer’s solution.

Comment: See also [fonts - Replace a single letter in xelatex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620088/replace-a-single-letter-in-xelatex?rq=1)