# Using fontspec or XeTeX commands to replace certain characters in font

Tags: xetex, fontspec, characters, substitution

This will sound like a strange question, but there is a rhyme and reason for it.  Is there a way to have `fontspec` or XeTeX commands affect only letters of one case--say lowercase?  For example, suppose you wanted to substitute all lowercase characters in one font with those in another.  I think the answer is probably in some variation of David Carlisle's answer here: [Replace a single letter in xelatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/620088/replace-a-single-letter-in-xelatex).  Is there an easy way to do this or will it need to be done character-by-character?  I am interested in text mode.  David already showed me how to do this in math mode. I am using OpenType text fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill in all that you consider “lowercase”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\newfontfamily{\LCL}{Futura}% Lower Case Letters


\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\LOWERCASELETTERS

\count255=\numexpr`a-1\relax
\loop\ifnum\count255<`z
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \XeTeXcharclass \count255 \LOWERCASELETTERS
\repeat

\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \LOWERCASELETTERS {\begingroup\LCL}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \LOWERCASELETTERS 0 {\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \LOWERCASELETTERS {\begingroup\LCL}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \LOWERCASELETTERS 4095 {\endgroup}

\begin{document}

Some text AbCdE.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the substitution only for the main font, you can modify as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[
  NFSSFamily=mainfont,
]

\newfontfamily{\LCL}{Futura}% Lower Case Letters


\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\LOWERCASELETTERS

\count255=\numexpr`a-1\relax
\loop\ifnum\count255<`z
  \advance\count255 by 1
  \XeTeXcharclass \count255 \LOWERCASELETTERS
\repeat

% some syntactic sugar
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\replacemainfont}{}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeT { \use:c { f@family } } { mainfont } { \LCL }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\XeTeXinterchartoks 0 \LOWERCASELETTERS {\begingroup\replacemainfont}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \LOWERCASELETTERS 0 {\endgroup}
\XeTeXinterchartoks 4095 \LOWERCASELETTERS {\begingroup\replacemainfont}
\XeTeXinterchartoks \LOWERCASELETTERS 4095 {\endgroup}

\begin{document}

Some text AbCdE.

\textsf{Some text AbCdE.}

\texttt{Some text AbCdE.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One last question: is there a way to have this only affect one family (or for that matter a single font)?  I thought at first glance this would affect the main font but not the sans or mono, so I had hoped to modify the code to change only a particular family (which is probably sufficient for my purposes).  But this is replacing the lowercase in whatever the active font happens to be.

Comment: @MikePugh Added as requested

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed.  Thank you!