# Change font for '+' and '=' in text mode

Tags: fonts

I would like to change the fonts for `+` and `=` in text mode (NOT math font)

I mainly use both `article` and `beamer` document classes.

For `beamer` class, instead of `lmodern` font, I like `nimbussans` package for generic fonts, except for how it writes `+` and `=`.

For example, `lmodern` font renders

```
\begin{frame}{}
\[\text{1+1=2}\]
\[\text{1$+$1$=$2}\]
\[1+1=2\]
\end{frame}
```

to

[image]

while `nimbussans` font renders it to

[image]

I can add the following lines to change the math fonts for `+` and `=`

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{myoperators}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{myoperators}{bold}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{myoperators}{"2B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{myoperators}{"3D}
```

to get

[image]

However, I don't know how to change text font for `+` and `=`.

For `article` class, I like `newtxtext` package for generic fonts, but it has the same problem (problem for me):

[image]

---

MWE

```
% article MWE
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lmodern}   %option1
\usepackage{newtxtext}  %option2
\begin{document}
\[\text{1+1=2}\]
\[\text{1$+$1$=$2}\]
\[1+1=2\]
\end{document}

% beamer MWE
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}                    %option1
\usepackage[scaled=0.95]{nimbussans}    %option2
\DeclareSymbolFont{myoperators}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{myoperators}{bold}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{+}{\mathbin}{myoperators}{"2B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{=}{\mathrel}{myoperators}{"3D}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
\[\text{1+1=2}\]
\[\text{1$+$1$=$2}\]
\[1+1=2\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

EDIT

Based on`user202729`'s comment, I could come up with the following solution

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lmodern}   %option1
\usepackage{newtxtext}  %option2
\DeclareSymbolFont{myoperators}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{myoperators}{bold}{OT1}{lmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\myplus}{\mathbin}{myoperators}{"2B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\myequal}{\mathrel}{myoperators}{"3D}
\catcode`+=\active
\catcode`==\active
\def+{\ensuremath{\myplus}}
\def={\ensuremath{\myequal}}
\begin{document}
\[\text{1+1=2}\]
\[\text{1$+$1$=$2}\]
\[1+1=2\]
\end{document}
```

But I'm not sure whether this solution only works well in this MWE, or it will work well even with many other packages. Also I'm not sure this is the efficient/appropriate implementation.

Comment: [characters - Import a single letter from a different font (and use it in text mode) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468183/import-a-single-letter-from-a-different-font-and-use-it-in-text-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1) and linked questions

Comment: @user202729 Does it only work for luatex? I should have mentioned that I use pdflatex.

Comment: Tjen use catcode changing solutions then.  With caveats.

Comment: See [catcodes - Is it possible to redefine the character code of space? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649261/is-it-possible-to-redefine-the-character-code-of-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) for an example of catcode-changing method. Although actually in this case using virtual font might be more suitable [hyphenation - How to create a virtual font? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25852/how-to-create-a-virtual-font)

Comment: @user202729 Super Thank! Can you take a look at my trial?