# My math inline text is smaller than the normal text!

Tags: math-mode, fonts, fontsize, sans-serif

I have a little problem, when I'm writing, my inline math (marked with $...$) the font size seems to be smaller than the text font size. 
How can I make it the same size.?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{extarticle}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,top=1cm,right=2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
        decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
        matrix,shapes.symbols}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,textcomp}
    \everymath{\displaystyle}

    \usepackage{times}
    \renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
    \usepackage{tgheros}
    \usepackage[defaultmono,scale=0.85]{droidmono}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{20.0pt}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=10mm,right=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=15mm}

    \linespread{1.3}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Vi har altså at både $a$ og $b$ er positive tal og $a$ er forskellig fra $1$.\\
Konstanten $a$ kaldes for 
\textcolor{blue!75!black}{\textbf{fremskrivningsfaktoren}}(eller grundtallet), 
mens konstanten $b$ kaldes for \textcolor{blue!75!black}{\textbf{begyndelsesværdien}} 
fordi grafen for den ekspoenetielle funktion skærer y-aksen i punktet $(0,b)$, 
dette kan vi vise på følgende måde ved at indsætte $x=0$ i forskriften.
\[
f(0)=b\cdot a^0=b\cdot 1=b
\]
\end{document}
```

The outcome is like this where you can see that a and b is smaller than the text around it.

[image: My problem]

Hope someone can help me.!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Sincerely your default font does not fit with mathematical computer modern font. Modern computer fonts are not small but it is the text font that is not beautiful.

Comment: Can you help me what to do, to make it the same size!?

Comment: You might want to visit TUG.dk/FontCatalogue,

Comment: Have you considered getting rid of the three directives `\usepackage{times}`, `\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}`, and `\usepackage{tgheros}` and, in their stead, writing `\usepackage{arev}`? Doing so will give you matched sans-serif text and math fonts.

Comment: line 94: Option clash for package textcomp.  ...textcomp\RequirePackage[full]{textcomp}\fi
: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
: Over-specification in `v'-direction.

Comment: For a hands-on comparison of the "look" of various text and math fonts, see the answers to the query [Suggest a “nice” font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5001). Shameless self-citation alert: I posted the most-upvoted answer to this query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The x-height of the sans-serif font you're working with -- `tgheros`, an Helvetica clone -- is much larger than the x-height of your math font, which is Computer Modern. As far as I know, the `tgheros` package doesn't provide a scaling option. However, if you replace

```
\usepackage{tgheros}
```

with

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.78]{helvet}
```

and change the document font size from `11pt` to `14pt`, the scaling mismatch will have been alleviated significantly. (As you can probably guess, the `helvet` package provides another Helvetica clone.)

[image]

Comment: Hi, dear friend. I vote +1 your answer. For my opinion the combination helvetica+cm is very ugly.

Comment: @Sebastiano - I fully agree with you on the proposition that Helvetica and Computer Modern don't mix. However, that determination isn't for us to make, is it? All we can help with, realistically, is with eliminating the sizing mismatch...

Comment: It is true but for my opinion I have suggested to change the font. My is nice. :-). I also like aesthetics as well as answering questions.

Comment: @Sebastiano - I've already upvoted your answer. :-) Let's see if the OP weighs in and provides a bit more information about why he/she is using a combination of a sans-serif text font and a serif math font.

Comment: If you find the upvotes you remember that there are also mine. :-)

Comment: The 10th upvote on this answer made me earn the 997th and 998th badge on this site. Many thanks!!

Comment: For friends, I do this and more. Always in the leg. You're very excellent user. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano - Thanks!! I'll let you know when I make to 1000. :-)

Answer (score 4):

For my opinion this font `Antykwa Półtawskiego` for the text is better than helvetica.

[image]

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{extarticle}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage[left=2cm,top=1cm,right=2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,tikzmark}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,%
        decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,%
        matrix,shapes.symbols}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,textcomp}
    \everymath{\displaystyle}

    \usepackage{times}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \usepackage{antpolt}
    \usepackage[defaultmono,scale=0.85]{droidmono}

    \usepackage{multicol}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{20.0pt}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=10mm,right=10mm,top=10mm,bottom=15mm}

    \linespread{1.3}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Vi har altså at både $a$ og $b$ er positive tal og $a$ er forskellig fra $1$.\\
Konstanten $a$ kaldes for \textcolor{blue!75!black}{\textbf{fremskrivningsfaktoren}}(eller grundtallet), mens konstanten $b$ kaldes for \textcolor{blue!75!black}{\textbf{begyndelsesværdien}} fordi grafen for den ekspoenetielle funktion skærer y-aksen i punktet $(0,b)$, dette kan vi vise på følgende måde ved at indsætte $x=0$ i forskriften.
\begin{center}
$f(0)=b\cdot a^0=b\cdot 1=b$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: IMO they still does not look good together, too much contrast in "color" (I keep forgetting the technical term)

Comment: @daleif The color is the original of the OP. You are authorized to edit my answer.

Comment: The op probably did not know any better.

Comment: @Sebastiano in this case "color" does not refer to blue/red/whatever, it refers to the intensity of the black strokes in term of black/white ratio on the page. Computer Modern has a different color than the font you suggest. See also: http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/sgrais/typographic_color.htm

Comment: @Andrea Lazzarotto:  Surely as I wrote in a previous comment the font font used contrasts totally with the default CM character. Even Helvet Helvet clone ill-suited, despite the talented Mico, has reduced the size of the character. Personally the combination, and I write truthfully, I did not the best, but at least the visual impact is less poor.