# stix package in nomath mode

Tags: stix

I have a big physics book typed in latex with standard fonts, including many math font packages (`bm`, `double strike`, `ams`, etc.). The manuscript has been checked carefully by several readers.

The editor says that they wish to switch to the STIX fonts. I checked that this introduces many problems in the formulas; for instance, the `simplewick` package does not work well anymore (I can give more details on these problems if anyone is interested).

I thought that the solution was simple: use STIX in the `nomath` mode, so that only the fonts of the text should be changed:

```
\usepackage[nomath]{stix}
```

I was naively expecting that my formulas would be treated exactly as before using STIX. In fact, this improves the situation a lot, but some serious problems remain. For instance the commands `\gtrsim` and `\leqslant` seem to be no longer recognized.

Am I doing some trivial mistake? Many thanks in advance for any advice.

Franck

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[nomath]{stix}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Some text to see the fonts
$ a \gtrsim b $
$A \leqslant B $
\begin{equation}
\lvert(\psi_{1},\psi_{2})\rvert
\leqslant
\sqrt{(\psi_{1},\psi_{1})}\;\sqrt{(\psi_{2},\psi_{2})}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

@JoKalliauer Thanks Jo for your kind interest! I was handling two volumes of a quantum mechanics book,  about 1500 pages, which have been typed in latex with standard fonts. Using stix fonts is easy, and creates no problem in the text. On the other hand, it does introduce problems in some equations: because the size of the fonts has changed, some alignments are destroyed and the equations become harder  to read (Wick contractions actulally become impossible to understand). I thought that the solution was to keep the stix fonts for the text only, and use the  [nomath] command. Alas, this does not work: the equations are still modified with this command, for some mysterious reason.The final result is that I told the publisher that it was not possible to use the stix fonts, and they agreed - there was no other solution anyway, except retyping too many pages. Still, this seems to mean that there is something wrong with the [nomath] command.

Thanks again!     Franck

Comment: will the publishers be happy with that? stix is pretty much a Times clone so the only reason to use it is to get the matching math font.

Comment: AFAICT, the stix fonts haven't been updated in quite a while. Can you try to convince the publisher to give the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages a try?

Comment: @Mico stix2 isn't that old (but not yet set up for 8bit tex by default)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - `stix2` is quite different from `stix` (at least in the unicode-math version). I was referring strictly to the earlier, `stix` version. That said, I'm a big fan of the Stix Two fonts -- both math and text. If the OP can make use of LuaLaTeX and the `unicode-math` package, I would whole-heartedly recommend he seriously consider the `Stix Two` fonts.

Comment: @Mico there's no real reason why stix2 can't be used with latex just as stix 1 can (that was part of the original spec, they just haven't got round to re-packaging the fonts yet in the encoding Khaled used for stix1....)

Comment: Sorry, but this seems too broad, without examples to test on.

Comment: `\gtrsim` is defined by stix package (by default) and by the `amssymb` package, so if you pass `nomath` to stix and include `amssymb` I would expect it to be defined.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, do have a look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59706/5001) to the posting [Suggest a “nice” font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59702/5001); it mentions several Times Roman clones (both text and math), for use under pdfLaTeX. [Warning: Shameless self-citation alert!]

Comment: Thank you very much for all these interesting comments and suggestions! I will try newtxtext and newtxmath as Mico suggests. My initial question remains: why do commands such as \gtrsim and \leqslant (and probably other commands) work with STIX without any option, and stop working with the nomath option? This is just the opposite of the expected behavior. I found nothing mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @Franck can you give a minimal working example, why you need [nomath], because I would just remove it.