# Trouble installing a font family

Tags: fonts, texmaker

I want to use a combination of fonts I saw [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97128/203432) but I don't know how to install them correctly. I tried running the code in the answer but I get an error saying *mathpazo* is unknown. Up until now I've only used the default font so I have no experience with this topic. I'm using Texmaker and Windows. Any help is appreciated :)

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}

\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}   % With old-style figures and real smallcaps.
\linespread{1.025}              % Palatino leads a little more leading

% Euler for math and numbers
\usepackage[euler-digits,small]{eulervm}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\hbar}{\hslash}}

\usepackage{ntheorem}

% No easy way of putting the theorem description in italics?
% It seems I need to define a new style...
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}% 
   {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}% 
   {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ \textit{(##3)}\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}

\newtheorem{theorem}{theorem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}

\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{theorem}[Residue Theorem]
Let $f$ be analytic in the region $G$ except for the isolated 
singularities $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$. If $\gamma$ is a closed 
rectifiable curve in $G$ which does not pass through any of the 
points $a_k$ and if $\gamma\approx 0$ in $G$, then
\[
  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\! f = \sum_{k=1}^m 
  n(\gamma;a_k)\Res(f;a_k)\,.
\]
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Vincent I've added a screenshot :)

Comment: Good! I guess you're using MiKTeX 2.9? Also, when sharing code with others on this site, it's always a better idea to post it as text, so that others can copy and paste it to see what's wrong. It's always easier to help this way!

Comment: @Vincent Yes I'm using MikTeX 2.9. I took the code I used from the answer I linked in my question (where it is already in text form)!

Comment: Did you check into the MiKTeX Console to see if the package ``mathpazo`` is installed? If not, the first thing to do is certainly to install it, which you could do manually in the MiKTeX Console. Then you might have to "Refresh font map files", which is under the "Tasks" menu.

Comment: Please post it here in text form anyway. (1) It is easier. (2) It won't change if the link does. (3) It makes the content of your question searchable for future users with the same problem. (4) It works for screen readers which many visually impaired people rely on. (5) It is easier not to have to click and then hope you remember where the new question is etc.

Comment: mathpazo is in miktex in the psnfss package. Install it with the miktex console. It is rather curious that miktex tries to install mathpazo instead. Better update also the package database (menu tasks, in user and admin mode) and check for updates (user and admin mode).

Comment: @cfr I understand and I've edited the question again :)

Comment: I tried all of your suggestions and noticed that something was probably wrong with my miktex installation (basically trying to do anything in the console produced an error). After reinstalling miktex everything worked instantly :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks for editing!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was resolved by reinstalling MikTeX as mentioned by the OP in comments.

Comment: @ZachariasZarowski Note that it isn't 'off-topic' at all, but there are a limited number of reasons available for closing questions and this one lets me add a comment with the real reason.