# Good TeX text, math and webfont?

Tags: fonts

There are lots of nice fonts listed in [Suggest a "nice" font family for my basic LaTeX template (text and math)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math) .

does anyone have a nice corresponding listing for good fonts that also include a corresponding webfont?  this is particularly appealing for creating web pages that look similar to the latex source while adding mathjax...and or mix with png created by latex.

Comment: What exactly makes a font a “webfont”? Modern web typography (much like current flavors of LaTeX) can make use of practically any font.

Comment: https://latex.now.sh/

Comment: webfont: something that is hosted by a good cdn and requires just one css statement to include.

Answer (score 3):

MathJax [version 2](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/font-support.html) currently supports STIX, Asana, Neo Euler, Pagella, Termes or Latin Modern.  MathJax 3 currently supports only STIX.

Latin Modern matches Computer Modern and its clones, Termes matches Times or its clones, STIX has its own companion font, and the others match Palatino.

MathML supports [any OpenType math font.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available)

You also have the option to convert your equation to a SVG and embed that on a webpage.