# What is the font used in this lecture note?

Tags: fonts

I've come across [this](https://minterscompactness.files.wordpress.com/2019/01/Differential_Geometry_Part_II_Notes.pdf) lecture note. I feel that the font making reading the note at ease.

[image]

I have come across this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59702/suggest-a-nice-font-family-for-my-basic-latex-template-text-and-math/59706), but could not find the matching font.

Could you elaborate on this what is this font?

Comment: as you have the pdf just look at the font menu in your pdf viewer or use the `pdffonts ` commandline utility to list them all

Comment: From the PDF information, you can see that the font for the running text is [Charter BT (Italic)](https://www.linotype.com/de/1083161/charter-bt-italic-product.html),

Comment: CharterBT-Roman  and MathDesign-CH-Regular-Symbol-10 and related fonts mostly, set with TeXPadTeX on an iphone.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you so much for your help! I can obtain similar effect with `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` or `\usepackage[charter,cal=cmcal]{mathdesign}`.