# Could someone help identify what user package this could be?

Tags: fonts

I traditionally use the following user packages

```
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{asymptote} 
\usepackage{changepage} 
\usepackage{color}      
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{framed}    
\usepackage{geometry}   
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{helvet}    
\usepackage{marginnote} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}  
\usepackage{multicol}   
\usepackage{multirow}   
\usepackage{pgffor}    
\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage{tikz}       
\usepackage{totalcount} 
\usepackage{accents}
```

which produces these styles:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However I was wondering if anyone could identify the user package that produces the following symbols that I'm trying to imitate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

That is, could someone name the package (or a package) that gives straight upward and thinner integral signs, thicker summation  signs and a thinner flick on the square root as default?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59706/234654) can be a reference.

Comment: There are some crucial bits of information missing at the moment. For sure, in order to generate the first group of three screenshots, it is *not* sufficient to load the`amsmath` and `amssymb` packages. The first three screenshots you provide all show that some kind of Times Roman (clone) font is in use. Which font package do you employ to generate the screenshots? Please be specific.

Comment: @Mico I have updated my question to include all the user packages I am currently using in my document, does this new information help you identify how I can change my doc to suit the desired examples?

Comment: @Quippy - Thanks. Indeed, it's the instruction `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` that's responsible for loading Times Roman clone text and math fonts. The appearance of the first three screenshots is determined entirely by this instruction. The fact that you also load (among many other packages) the `amsmath` and `amssymb`  packages is pretty much irrelevant.

Comment: @Mico, thank you, do you perhaps know any font replacements that can get me close to those last three examples?

Comment: (lookup table: [Which OpenType Math fonts are available? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425098/which-opentype-math-fonts-are-available) // [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A preliminary remark: To generate the math expressions shown in the first three screenshots, it suffices to load the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. Loading the other packages is ok, but they don't influence the apperance of the expressions in question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext} 
\usepackage{newtxmath} 
\begin{document}
\[
\int\frac{1}{1+\cos x}\,dx \quad \sqrt{mg} \quad \sum_{n=1}^k 5n
\]
\end{document}
```

On to the final three screenshots:

- To generate upright rather than slanted integral symbols, while keeping the Times Roman clone math font, just load the `newtxmath` package with the option `upint`: `\usepackage[upint]{newtxmath}`.
- To generate the squashed-looking summation symbol, load either the `mathptmx` or the `stix` package instead of the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages. (I have no idea, though, why anyone would prefer the squashed-looking summation symbols...)
- Keep loading the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages to output `\sqrt{n!}` as in the final screenshot.