# Math fonts with Times New Roman

Tags: fonts, math-mode

Which math fonts I can use with times new roman as font for the text? I'm looking for a math font that best fit in my document. Any suggest are appreciate

Comment: '\usepackage{mathptmx}' provides Times roman for both text and math mode. Please also consult [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/) for additonal fonts that provides both text and math mode.

Comment: In addition to the comment of @PeterJansson, there is this post that possibly answers your question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/times-new-roman-fonts-and-maths-without-mathptmx

Comment: I found asana-math. How can I use it?

Comment: You also might want to consider [newtx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) which provides a Times-like text (`newtxtext`) and math font (`newtxmath`).

Comment: @Mazzy you need [unicode-math](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) and to add `\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}` to your document.

Comment: Which operating system are you on? And which LaTeX format -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX -- do you use?

Comment: @hakaze Asana Math is *not* compatible with Times, as it's based on Palatino

Comment: @egreg my advice was not based on the usefulness of Asana Math in combination with Times, but on @Mazzy's inquiry on how to use both together in one document. I also provided an appropriate alternative (`newtx`) in my other comment.

Comment: As it stands, the direct link to TeX is not so clear in the question (font matching is a graphics issue). Asking how to load particular fonts would be more on-topic, but even then I think we'd want more detail.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two opentype math fonts based on the Times New Roman font:

- XITS Math https://github.com/khaledhosny/xits-math
- Tex Gyre Termes Math http://oldwww.gust.org.pl/gustnews/tg-termes-math-en

To install them you need XeLatex or LuaLatex and the unicode-math package.

Comment: My Latex seems to be using a font called "Latin Modern Math"