# class svjour3 Package mathptmx Warning: There are no bold math fonts on input line nn

Tags: mathptmx

Without **mathptmx** there are no compilation errors but if I use `\RequirePackage{mathptmx}` before the `\documentclass[smallextended,final]{svjour3}` or use `\usepackage{mathptmx}` after it I got the error:

```
*Package mathptmx Warning: There are no bold math fonts on input line nn*
```

The error refers to:

```
\maketitle       % previous line
\begin{abstract} % line nn
```

The preamble includes:

```
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
% use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
\RequirePackage{mathptmx}  
%
\documentclass[smallextended,final]{svjour3} % onecolumn (second format)
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[]{units}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}  
\usepackage{hyperref}
\journalname{Found Phys}
```

The error goes away if I remove all the elements intrinsic to the class svjour3 and use the article class.

The use of the package mathptmx is recommended by Springer but the warning is annoying.

How can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all you should *not* load `amsmath`, `amsfonts` and `mathptmx` before `\documentclass`. You also don't need `fix-cm`, since you're using a different font set than Computer Modern.

The issue is simply that `mathptmx` does not provide bold math fonts, whereas `svjour3` applies `\boldmath` to its sectional titles.

Use a font set based on Times that has bold math fonts.

```
\documentclass[smallextended,final]{svjour3} % onecolumn (second format)
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{units}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\journalname{Found Phys}

\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
```

Comment: I'm using \dfrac from the amsmath package. The mathptmx is mentioned in the template and instructions of the class...

Comment: @HelderVelez You should consider “inertia”: `mathptmx` used to be the only free package providing Times also for math; it's not so any more.

Comment: @HelderVelez -- the comment was not suggesting to remove `amsmath`; it was that `\usepackage{amsmath}` (and other packages) should be loaded *after* the `\documentclass` line.

Comment: My instalation ignores inertia.sty. I can not install inertia on a machine that I can not control (the Springer editor) .  I had to use the 
\RequirePackage{amsmath} before the \documentclass because the  Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \vec

Comment: I found advice on [TeX.SE - Times New Roman fonts and maths WITHOUT mathptmx](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56876/times-new-roman-fonts-and-maths-without-mathptmx)  by @egreg.

Answer (score 1):

I made my setup like this and it gives me no warnings.

```
    \RequirePackage{fix-cm,amsmath}
%
%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
%\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\documentclass[twocolumn,draft]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}      % use Times fonts if available on your TeX system
%
% insert here the call for the packages your document requires
%\usepackage{latexsym}
% etc.
%
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{}
%
% Insert the name of "your journal" with
\journalname{Nonlinear Dynamics}
%
\begin{document}
```

`\mathptmx` is obsolete. You should use the `\newtx` package in its place. I suggest reading the documentation on CTAN for more info.

Comment: @Al_Fh : Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What about `mathptmx`? Helder Velez got an error with mathptmx...